# For instructions like Load R2,B where is the B address? An address is a machine word so how can there be room for the operation and the address

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture

For RISC architecture instructions like Load R2,B where is the B address? An address is a machine word so how can there be room for the operation and the address in the instruction if the instruction is just one word?

Comment: Please show a real world example of the type of instruction you're talking about. RISC instruction sets typically only support register-indirect addressing with a (relatively) small immediate offset for loads/stores. For example, `ldr r0, [r1, #16]` on ARM, or `sw $t0, 8($a2)` on MIPS.

Comment: @Michael I don't have a real world example, I'm learning this in class and we're using assembly notation instead of an actual assembly language.

Comment: If the machine has one word instructions that does not mean that in one word it needs to encode also the addresses. That word is used to encode the instruction code and the involved registers. The CPU instruction decoder will know to interpret the following word as an address used in the previous instruction.

Answer (score 2):

Some architectures support PC-relative addressing, where the instruction contains a value that is added to or subtracted from the program counter (instruction pointer) in order to generate the target address.  Most programs are small enough that most things they need to load are within a distance from the PC that can be encoded in a limited number of bits.

Comment: and if not within reach you can then put the absolute address within reach, then do a second load  ldr r2,addr_of_thing,  ldr r3,[r2]